# Чем отличается вектор a.shape (60000,) от вектора b.shape (60000, 0) от вектора c.shape (60000,1)?

Tags: python, numpy

Отличие вектора от матрицы(тензора) - в чем состоит? И как reshape сделать на 100 процентов что-то именно вектором?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Чем отличаются размерности `(N,)`, `(N, 0)`, `(N, 1)` ?

Размерность `(N,)` - говорит о том, что это `1D` вектор (можно представлять его как список, состоящий из скалярных значений).

Пример:

```
In [5]: a = np.array([1,2,3])

In [6]: a
Out[6]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [7]: a.shape
Out[7]: (3,)
```

---

Размерность `(N, M)` - говорит о том, что это `2D` тензор / матрица (можно представлять его как таблицу, состоящую из `N` строк и `M` столбцов).

пример матрицы размерности `(3, 1)`:

```
In [8]: b = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

In [9]: b
Out[9]:
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [10]: b.shape
Out[10]: (3, 1)
```

пример матрицы размерности `(3, 2)`

```
In [11]: c = np.array([[1, 10],[2, 20],[3, 30]])

In [12]: c
Out[12]:
array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 3, 30]])

In [13]: c.shape
Out[13]: (3, 2)
```

Размерность `(N, 0)` - говорит о том, что матрица пустая - не содержит столбцов.

---

**Резюмируя выше сказанное:**

- `(N,)` - `1D` вектор (или список скаляров)
- `(N, 1)` - `2D` тензор / матрица с `N` строк и единственным столбцом
- `(N, 0)` - `2D` пустой тензор / матрица с `N` строк и `0` столбцов

Answer (score 3):

> Как преобразовать тензор / матрицу любой размерности в одномерный
>   вектор?

Чтобы преобразовать тензор / матрицу любой (N) размерности в 1D вектор, можно воспользоваться [numpy.ravel()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

Пример:

```
In [32]: a3d = np.random.randint(10, size=(4,3,2))

In [33]: a3d
Out[33]:
array([[[6, 2],
        [3, 0],
        [6, 8]],

       [[2, 7],
        [9, 2],
        [6, 4]],

       [[6, 5],
        [9, 7],
        [7, 1]],

       [[4, 2],
        [3, 0],
        [8, 3]]])

In [34]: a1d = a3d.ravel()

In [35]: a1d
Out[35]: array([6, 2, 3, 0, 6, 8, 2, 7, 9, 2, 6, 4, 6, 5, 9, 7, 7, 1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 8, 3])

In [36]: a1d.shape
Out[36]: (24,)
```

---

> Как увеличить размерность вектора / тензора, сохранив общее число элементов?

Для увеличения размерности можно воспользоваться методом [numpy.reshape()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

```
In [42]: a = np.arange(1, 13)

In [43]: a
Out[43]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])

In [44]: a.shape
Out[44]: (12,)

In [45]: a2d = a.reshape(4, 3)

In [46]: a2d
Out[46]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])

In [47]: a2d.shape
Out[47]: (4, 3)
```

Если указать `-1` в качестве одной из размерностей, то `Numpy` попытается вычислить данную размерность самостоятельно:

```
In [48]: b = a.reshape(-1, 6)

In [49]: b
Out[49]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]])

In [50]: b.shape
Out[50]: (2, 6)
```

Часто в задачах ML ("Machine Learning") требуется преобразовать вектор в тензор с одним столбцом - это делается так:

```
In [52]: a
Out[52]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])

In [53]: a.shape
Out[53]: (12,)

In [54]: b = a.reshape(-1, 1)

In [55]: b
Out[55]:
array([[ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [ 5],
       [ 6],
       [ 7],
       [ 8],
       [ 9],
       [10],
       [11],
       [12]])

In [56]: b.shape
Out[56]: (12, 1)
```